# What kind of video or audio encoding is causing this?

Tags: video-quality, streaming, transcoding, audio-quality

Trying to stream a video (mkv) on a [Samsung 2017 TV](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/media-specifications/2017-tv-video-specifications.html) and some videos are "lagging" / buggy. I don't know the term for this kind of issue so it's hard for me to pinpoint the problem.

The video stream is AVC, the audio AAC LC.

I did try to re-encode into a different format, but it's not always a sure shot. If someone can point me in the right direction as to how this issue is called and how properly convert if needed, it'd be appreciated.

The file is transferred through a network base app called Jellyfin, no transcoding is being applied.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is dropping data when trying to stream to the client device.

Take your original footage and re-encode it using several different bitrates for the video. See which ones drop out and which ones work with your network connection. You can convert videos using e.g.  [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) (free) or [Media Encoder](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/media-encoder.html) (not free).

This should give you a sense of how many megabits per second can be streamed over your network. Then you need to decide whether to transcode your videos in advance, or whether you have a server with enough processing power to transcode them on the fly.